# Terminal Keeps Opening

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, terminal, memory

I am a musician running ProTools and Maschine on my MacBook Air. I recently used Terminal.app to delete some standard Apple apps and clear disk space.

The space was cleared but now Terminal *keeps opening and interrupting me*. I enter the logout command and it logs out successfully but keeps coming back. I have run Etrecheck and there was nothing insidious on the system.

Is anyone aware of how to address this issue?

**Please note that I have not (and cannot!) update OS X because I've heard that it has operating problems with ProTools 12.**

System specs:
MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012)
1.8 GHz Intel Core i5
8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Macintosh HD
Intel HD Graphics 4000 1024 MB
OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5

Comment: Have you tried quitting Terminal.app by clicking Terminal.app in the Dock, and from the "Terminal" menu selecting "Quit"? ... If you have done so, please detail what exactly happens when it "interrupts" you - i.e. what is written in the window that pops up, and when does this happen?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I try to "Quit" but Terminal re-opens over and over. By interrupting I mean that the Macbook defaults to that window, so to speak, so if I am typing in the browser as I am now, the active window switches to terminal. Here is what the Terminal command line reads:

Comment: Last login: Sat Nov 12 16:27:10 on ttys000
Joshuas-Air:~ joshua[my last name]$

Comment: So it opens by itself when you're working on the Mac? Not just when you boot the Mac? ... How often does it open?

Comment: Yes it opens while I'm working after I close it. It will not stay closed. Also, if it's open in the background, from time to time it becomes the active window. So, for example, if I am typing in this screen, I will be stopped momentarily and have to click back in to make it my active window. Thus, it's a really annoying interruption. I would really like to just close Terminal and be done with it! Thanks.

Comment: It opens within minutes of my closing it. Sometimes with in seconds.

Comment: Did you add anything custom to launchd? - I.e. have you installed any kind of third party services, or added cron entries or similar?

Comment: I was using a VPN finder for a time. Also, Pro Tools runs an Application Manager. I've ended my subscription with the VPN application an uninstalled/deleted. When I write the command "logout" in Terminal it says "Process completed" but then it reopens.

Comment: Are you following some sort of guide or similar? - I.e. why are you writing "logout" and not simply closing the window? It sounds like you ran some Terminal commands - can you list what they were? - Perhaps something was incorrect?

Comment: I'm just writing the command "logout" in the hopes that it will prevent Terminal from continuing to open. As an update — after I deleted the VPN application, it seems to have stopped...!? I can't say for sure but I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: I have Pro Tools 12.7.1 and sometimes a terminal icon appears in the dock periodically. I thought it was some kind of malware but it seems just something between OS X and Avid applications.
I think Avid should know that there's a bug somewhere out there.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this exact problem all day and think I just found the solution too it.

I too thought that the problem was being caused by Terminal but I think it's just Application Manager acting up. For whatever reason Application Manager kept opening along with Terminal, only with no indication that it was open. Try quitting Application Manager and see if that works.

I know most of the people have this same issue also have Pro Tools so it could just be something stupid Application Manager is doing. Hope it works for you or get you on the phone with ProTools support to help fix the cofiguration or bug in that app/suite that is opening the terminal app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm usually not the one to figure things out. LOL. But, I trashed Application Manager and the Terminal opening problem stopped. Not sure if that was a bad idea, but I'm backed up :-)

Comment: What exactly is Application Manager? It is definitely not one of the built-in macOS apps. In addition, the other answer written a few years ago to the question also says the problem was resolved by quitting Application Manager. Have you tried that instead of deleting it?